My own tap drill system
I've been working with my own tap drill system ever since I came across this diagram:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/ISO_and_UTS_Thread_Dimensions.svg
So the tap drill is determined by:
$D_{maj} - \sqrt 3 * 5 / 16 * P$
Even though I reside in North America, I center my tooling to the metric system. Mostly because also, I source my material internationally online, where they are conventionally in metric.
So say I'm working with an M4 screw, using the formula, the tap drill I would ideally need is 3.6211 mm in diameter. Of course that's not to be found. So I would simply round down to 3.6 mm (if I happen to have it) or more typically 3.5 mm.
What I would have typically have at hand is a set of drill bits that are stepped in 0.5 mm. So what my ideal tap drill is always rounded down to those 0.5 mm increments.
So my question is: Is having a difference of less than 0.5 mm between the drill hole & finished tapped too much? Would it  cause bad tapping? Might it wear down the tap too much or even cause the tap to break? Would this be more the case if we go down the smaller screws like M2?

The tapping drill sizes are best found using Zeuss tables. see https://www.arceurotrade.co.uk/Catalogue/Books/ZEUS-Precision-Reference-Tables?srsltid=AfmBOoq6PpPdKU_oPJON4PTyLjL3oPUDhhw01s5UB7cDTJTOB1mYxaKM

Alright, just me answer this, for every tapping, would the tap be able clear for the $D_{min}$, if there is an excess of less than a 0.5mm in the pre-drilled hole?

Phrased another way, what's the minimum hole diameter that a tap can tap, if the pre-drilled hole is less than $D_{min}$?

Why not use the tables to get the drill size?

Because in case it, say, asks for a tap drill of 0.1063" (2.7 mm) & I only have a 2.5 mm for sure, then there's the excess of 0.2 mm from the ideal hole size. Would a tap be able to clear out that 0.2 into $D_{min}$? I don't know.

Also, I don't know how to look up this Zeus Table. I'm a parametric guy.


You can certainly get closer than 0.5mm to the correct size. Check mcmaster.
If the drill is too small, the torque required to cut the threads will be increased, since the tap will be cutting more material. If you're tapping plastic it certainly won't be an issue. Aluminum, probably fine, stainless steel almost certain to be an issue. In my experience the smaller the tap the more of a problem this is.
The drill size sets Dmin from your drawing:


If the tap drill is too small this will depend on the tap and not be controlled. I personally don't worry about it except when tapping M3 and smaller size holes in thick stainless steel. I honestly don't know of any downside to having the teeth too long except increased tapping force required.
